# Snowflake Snowpark Python - Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I utilized the Snowpark Python (private preview) to do some data engineering tasks (transform the data from a raw state to a clean state). How do I upload the Python code to Snowflake to then run it?

I think it needs to be a stored procedure but I can not find any documentation on how to create a stored procedure in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snowpark Stored Procedures for Python — Preview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-06.html#snowpark-stored-procedures-for-python-preview) was relased in June 2022.

---

Documentation is avaiable at [Writing Stored Procedures in Snowpark (Python)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-python.html)

Example:

> In an in-line stored procedure, you write your Python code in the AS clause of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. For example:
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROC(from_table STRING, to_table STRING, count INT)
>   RETURNS STRING
>   LANGUAGE PYTHON
>   RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
>   PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
>   HANDLER = 'run'
> AS
> $$
> def run(session, from_table, to_table, count):
>   session.table(from_table).limit(count).write.save_as_table(to_table)
>   return "SUCCESS"
> $$;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Lukasz Szozda's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070879/lukasz-szozda) answer, we could write the python code in a file and upload it to a Snowflake stage. Then write a  procedure to invoke the code from the stage. Attaching link for reference: [Code uploaded from stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-python.html#choosing-to-create-a-stored-procedure-with-in-line-code-or-with-code-uploaded-from-a-stage)